# SDMX-Json Parsing - No Time_Period problem - OECD Dataset python extract

Tags: python, json, parsing, blob, sdmx

I am using the python library `pandaSDMX` to extract entire datasets from the OECD database, and convert them to a CSV format (any readable format would be OK, because I want to put the final output in an SQL database).

To have access to a OECD dataset in SDMX-Json format (there is also a SDMXML format), you can paste on the browser a link like this one:

> **http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/PART2/all/all**
>
> Note: 'PART2' is the name of the dataset

The problem is, there are some OECD datasets for which SDMX-Json **does not have** a dimension named *Time_Period*, and ALL the sdmx-json parsing python libraries that I've found **only parse SDMX-Json that have this dimension**.

I've also tried to find some python library that could parse a SDMXML (SDMX-ML) file (that would also be OK), but building that process in python is not working for me...

Here is the piece of the code that I use to parse the SDMX-Json datasets and write the output CSV file on Azure blob storage:

```
# itera sob cada ficheiro json e converte o conteudo para csv
    for dataset in datasetList:
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()

        Values = [dataset, datasetFiltersList[counter]]
        cursor.execute(SQLLogCommand, Values)
        cnxn.commit()

        #logging.info('Analysing dataset: ' + dataset)
        try:
            data_response = oecd.data(resource_id=dataset, key=datasetFiltersList[counter])
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            Values = [datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'), 'Unicode Decode Error - Error', 0]
            cursor.execute(SQLUpdateCommand, Values)
            cnxn.commit()
        except KeyError:
            Values = [datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'), 'Key Error - Error', 0]
            cursor.execute(SQLUpdateCommand, Values)
            cnxn.commit()
        else:
            data = data_response.data
            if data.dim_at_obs == 'TIME_PERIOD':
                df = createDF(data, useIDs=False)
                blobService.create_blob_from_text(CONTAINERNAME, csvBlobPath + dataset + '.csv' , df.to_csv(index=False, sep='|', encoding='utf-8'))

                Values = [datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'), 'Success', 1]
                cursor.execute(SQLUpdateCommand, Values)
            cnxn.commit()  
            #logging.info('Dataset ' + dataset + ' analysed!')
        else:
            print('no time period error on dataset: ' + dataset)
            Values = [datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'), 'No Time Period - Error', 0]
            cursor.execute(SQLUpdateCommand, Values)
            cnxn.commit()  

cnxn.close()
```

So, **my final question is**:

> Does anyone know a way to parse SDMX-Json files that not have a *Time_Period*
>   dimension? Or other way to extract automatically a entire dataset from
>   OECD and parse it...

As example:

1. Dataset with time period (this one works fine for me):
   http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/TALIS_EDUGPS/all/all
2. Dataset without time period:
   http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/PART2/all/all

Answer (score 0):

The package [`sdmx1`](https://sdmx1.readthedocs.io) (an improved fork of `pandaSDMX`) does not have the restriction you describe, and can be used to retrieve and parse this data.

Version 2.5.0 also handles an idiosyncrasy of this particular OECD data: that the structure part of the message describes a TIME_FORMAT (n.b. not TIME_PERIOD) attribute on each observation, but the observations do not actually include this attribute.

```py
>>> import sdmx
>>> OECD = sdmx.Client("OECD")
>>> message = OECD.data("PART2")
No AttributeValues for attribute <DataAttribute TIME_FORMAT>; discard

>>> message
<sdmx.DataMessage>
  <Header>
    id: '710c36ac-0beb-4781-b6d6-01d86476a10c'
    prepared: '2021-07-11T17:54:09.547694+00:00'
    sender: <Agency OECD: Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development>
    source: 
    test: False
  response: <Response [200]>
  DataSet (1)
  dataflow: <DataflowDefinition (missing id)>
  observation_dimension: <sdmx.model._AllDimensions object at 0x7f008efd7e80>

>>> sdmx.to_pandas(message.data[0])
LOCATION  IND    PER  GRD  FLD  MSR
AUS       10CAU  CHG  EIG  MAT  MN     11.430378
                                SE      6.079738
                           SCI  MN     -3.697873
                                SE      4.820530
                      FOG  MAT  MN      6.051900
                                         ...    
ZAF       8UTSR  END  EIG  SCI  SE      3.203199
                 INI  EIG  MAT  MN     60.268028
                                SE      3.864160
                           SCI  MN     55.894505
                                SE      3.500335
Name: value, Length: 18755, dtype: float64
```